# Excel find and high lite duplicate between two sheets containing a text within a word

Tags: excel

I am struggling with VLOOKUP, COUNTIF, SEARCH, COUNT but just can't get the result that I need. I have two sheets one containing list supplied from customer and the other one representing our base list.

Our base list has data in two columns (B and E) that should be searchable for specific word with in the text. Column B is not a problem as it contains only the necessary data. The problem is column E. Here a searchable word might be with in the text. But it is always a word there is no space. example "PERFORM  A320-27-1224" it will never appear as "PERFORM  A320-27- 1224". As you see here I would be looking for A320-27-1224 number.

So base sheet looks like this.
[image: Base sheet]

And the list provided from customer looks like this

[image: list from customer]

So I would like to high lite item on customer list that will tell me if for example 281247-01-1.R is listed in base list. In example below it does so cell in customer sheet needs to change the color

In general I need to take data from customer list column "E" and to a search on whole base list as data in customer list always has correct wording layout.

I hope this make sense. I haven't posted any code as I have tried at least 20 different scenarios and would just create a mess.

Comment: It's better to add your code. SO is about helping you with your understanding but without the code to work with, you are asking for unpaid labour to fix your problem. Can you share with us the closest you've come to succeeding?

Comment: Hi the closest I got to what I believe will solve my problem is the following code =INDEX(list,SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(list,A2))*ROW($1:$3))) from [link]https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-search-string-for-a-list-of-words but I obviously I lack on knowledge here. In this example it is looking at column H. and only from row 1-3. If I expand from 1-20 code stops working or at least is not giving the same result.  How do I change that it would be looking at different sheet and not only column H  (in my case Sheet 2. and the whole worksheet for specific word)

Comment: Ok I have figure it out the list part. How can I match list of rows to the number of items in the list. So if list included 3 row then we need this ROW($1:$3) and if list includes 10 it should be ($1:$10). Is there a better to link the two?

Comment: Hey I am still spinning around this code. So next best thing I found is this one 'code' =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(things,A1)))>0 

but [link]https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things

Comment: eddied text above 

Hey I am still spinning around this code. So next best thing I found is this one 'code' =SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(things,A1)))>0 

from [link]https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things

But what I see would fit best is if I am searching column A1 that with example text (hello world it is sunny) and the list that code is looking included not only the specific word but could include additional example column $C$1:$C$10  (big cats are in the world) result will bring me back word "world".